# Postgresql - What are the WAL filename limits?

Tags: postgresql, wal

Concerning postgresql WAL filename, what are the limits to the following?

- timeline
- xlog file
- segment

My understanding is that segment is limited to 00..FF (boundary-inclusive).

For instance, could the following WAL be produced by postgresql?

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FF
```

UPDATE:

I have since found the following in postgresql source code:

```
typedef uint32 TimeLineID
```

which allows from a data store the values 0x00000000..0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: I wish to see `FFFFFFFF` timeline...

Comment: Is it possible within postgresql?

Comment: i dont see any reason why not. but definitely never wondered

Comment: It would take a very, very, VERY long time to get there, unless you modified the code to increment the timeline faster. Since you have to do a promotion via recovery.conf for each timeline increment, you're never going to run out of timelines.